# Как сделать картинку адаптивно \ canvas

Tags: html, css, canvas

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно ли эту картинку нарисовать на канвасе как-нибудь, либо сделать адаптивной, что бы при уменьшении ширины экрана, когда съезжается текст, картинка увеличивалась в величине.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Достаточно просто использовать псевдоэлементы:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  margin: 16px;
  padding-left: 16px;
  font-size: 19px;
  border-left: 8px solid;
}

ul {
  padding: 1rem;
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul li {
  position: relative;
}

ul li::before {
  content: '—';
  position: absolute;
  left: -21px;
}

h2 {
  font-family: Arial;
  position: relative;
}

h2::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: -35px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 5px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="block">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta ab error quis asperiores temporibus minus est sit doloribus cupiditate laudantium voluptatibus, tempora voluptatum nostrum suscipit ratione tenetur sapiente numquam quidem.</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta ab error quis asperiores temporibus minus est sit doloribus cupiditate laudantium voluptatibus, tempora voluptatum nostrum suscipit ratione tenetur sapiente numquam quidem.</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta ab error quis asperiores temporibus minus est sit doloribus cupiditate laudantium voluptatibus, tempora voluptatum nostrum suscipit ratione tenetur sapiente numquam quidem.</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta ab error quis asperiores temporibus minus est sit doloribus cupiditate laudantium voluptatibus, tempora voluptatum nostrum suscipit ratione tenetur sapiente numquam quidem.</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta ab error quis asperiores temporibus minus est sit doloribus cupiditate laudantium voluptatibus, tempora voluptatum nostrum suscipit ratione tenetur sapiente numquam quidem.</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta ab error quis asperiores temporibus minus est sit doloribus cupiditate laudantium voluptatibus, tempora voluptatum nostrum suscipit ratione tenetur sapiente numquam quidem.</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta ab error quis asperiores temporibus minus est sit doloribus cupiditate laudantium voluptatibus, tempora voluptatum nostrum suscipit ratione tenetur sapiente numquam quidem.</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta ab error quis asperiores temporibus minus est sit doloribus cupiditate laudantium voluptatibus, tempora voluptatum nostrum suscipit ratione tenetur sapiente numquam quidem.</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta ab error quis asperiores temporibus minus est sit doloribus cupiditate laudantium voluptatibus, tempora voluptatum nostrum suscipit ratione tenetur sapiente numquam quidem.</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta ab error quis asperiores temporibus minus est sit doloribus cupiditate laudantium voluptatibus, tempora voluptatum nostrum suscipit ratione tenetur sapiente numquam quidem.</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta ab error quis asperiores temporibus minus est sit doloribus cupiditate laudantium voluptatibus, tempora voluptatum nostrum suscipit ratione tenetur sapiente numquam quidem.</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta ab error quis asperiores temporibus minus est sit doloribus cupiditate laudantium voluptatibus, tempora voluptatum nostrum suscipit ratione tenetur sapiente numquam quidem.</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta ab error quis asperiores temporibus minus est sit doloribus cupiditate laudantium voluptatibus, tempora voluptatum nostrum suscipit ratione tenetur sapiente numquam quidem.</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta ab error quis asperiores temporibus minus est sit doloribus cupiditate laudantium voluptatibus, tempora voluptatum nostrum suscipit ratione tenetur sapiente numquam quidem.</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta ab error quis asperiores temporibus minus est sit doloribus cupiditate laudantium voluptatibus, tempora voluptatum nostrum suscipit ratione tenetur sapiente numquam quidem.</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta ab error quis asperiores temporibus minus est sit doloribus cupiditate laudantium voluptatibus, tempora voluptatum nostrum suscipit ratione tenetur sapiente numquam quidem.</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```